# What's the different between txt and QTextEdit about their style

Tags: qt

When I copy the content from txt to the QTextEdit, I find the style of the content has changed.I'm so puzzled.Is this the reason for coding?How can I solve it?(System: Mac OS)

[image]

Comment: share the .txt ....

Comment: try to set the font into monospace `QFont font("Monospace");
font.setStyleHint(QFont::TypeWriter);`

Comment: Comment from @Simon will solve the "Circle to Ellipse" problem. But the other thing is still not clear. Why there are more Starts in QTextEdit than in file ... please share the file. We want to have a look into char-set and byte order.

Comment: Have you tried it with other chars than `*`? Please use `o` for example

Answer (score 1):

You either need to use a fixed-width font in your QTextEdit, or you need to handle text pasting yourself and append the text in HTML format, wrapped in `<pre> </pre>` tags.

It seems you don't have a need for complex, rich text editing, so just setting the font is probably what you want here:

```
#include <QFontDatabase>

// ...

myTextEdit->setFont(QFontDatabase::systemFont(QFontDatabase::FixedFont));
```

This will pick a suitable fixed-width font and should work on all platforms.